# Uncover and then recover in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I'm using the `\uncover` and `\only` commands in a Beamer file, but I want to be able to then cover up things again as I progress through the slides.  Here is an example where I have A implies B implies C showing up piece-by-piece using the `\uncover` command.  After this is done, I would like to re-cover the portion that says `$B \Longrightarrow C$` leaving `$A \Longrightarrow C$` in the end.  How would I do this?

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\center{\uncover<1->{$A$} \uncover<2->{$\Longrightarrow$} \uncover<3->{$B$} \uncover<4->{$\Longrightarrow$} \uncover<5->{$C$}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\centering
\uncover<1->{$A$} \uncover<2->{$\Longrightarrow$} \uncover<3-5>{$B$} \uncover<4-5>{$\Longrightarrow$} \uncover<5-6>{$C$}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]